# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Movie'

Tags: python, database, forms, formatting, psql

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong??
Im pulling the data from IMDBPY, everything matches but now it won't go in my tables?!

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Movie'
> [SQL: INSERT INTO movie (title, "cast", plot, username) VALUES (%(title)s, %(cast)s, %(plot)s, %(username)s) RETURNING movie.id]
> [parameters: {'title': <Movie id:0120338[http] title:*Titanic (1997)*>, 'cast': <Person id:0000138[http] name:*Leonardo DiCaprio*>, 'plot': 'A seventeen-year-old aristocrat falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.::j-jessie-weaver', 'username': 'plzwork'}]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

Movies table

```
class Movie(db.Model):
    """movies."""

    __tablename__ = "movie"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, 
                   primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100),
                      nullable=False)
    cast = db.Column(db.Text)
    plot = db.Column(db.Text)
    username = db.Column(
        db.String(20),
        db.ForeignKey('users.username'),
        nullable=False,
    )
```

Adding Movies to the Database

```
@app.route("/users/<username>/movies/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def movie_show(username):
    
    """Show  Movie Search Form and process it."""
    if 'username' not in session or username != session['username']:
        raise Unauthorized()
    
    form= MovieForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        title = form.title.data
        cast= form.cast.data
        plot=form.plot.data
        title=moviesDB.search_movie(title)[0]
        moviesDB.update(title)
        cast=title['cast'][0]
        moviesDB.update(title)
        plot=title['plot'][0]
        moviesDB.update(title)
        
        movie = Movie( 
        title=(title),
        cast=(cast),
        plot= (plot),
        username=username)
        
        
        print('title', title)
     
        print('plot', plot)
        db.session.add(movie)
        db.session.commit()
    
        return redirect(f"/users/{movie.username}")
        
    else:
        return render_template("movies/new.html", form=form)
register_adapter(Movie,movie_show)
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using another API omdbapi, created a function with json to grab the data, then I called the function to update my Models.Py. Even though no one answered my question, hope this solves someone's bug :)